# Google cloud vision API UnKnonHostException

Tags: android, google-cloud-vision

Can anyone help me why i am getting this issue.... But not always only some time....

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "vision.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname --------- Stack trace --------- java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:470) java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29) com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:220) com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:176) com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:108) com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:482) com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:465) com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:447) com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:353) com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:468) com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118) com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:249) com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218) com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25) com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77) com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972) com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419) com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352) com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469) com.skyvin.numr.scanreceipt.CropImage$13.doInBackground(CropImage.java:1243) com.skyvin.numr.scanreceipt.CropImage$13.doInBackground(CropImage.java:1186) android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) ------------------------------- --------- Cause --------- android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname) libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method) libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55) java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451) java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29) com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:220) com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:176) com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:108) com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:482) com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:465) com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:447) com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:353) com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:468) com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118) com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:249) com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218) com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25) com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77) com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972) com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419) com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352) com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469) com.skyvin.numr.scanreceipt.CropImage$13.doInBackground(CropImage.java:1243) com.skyvin.numr.scanreceipt.CropImage$13.doInBackground(CropImage.java:1186) android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your firewall may be blocking the request, or can be the issue with your internet connection. When this happens, try to ping vision.googleapis.com and check if ping can resolve the host.